# Azure Function keeps restarting with gprc worker error

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a very simple Azure Function like i've created a thousand, with an httptrigger.
The function is a .net 7 isolated function.
Intermittently i'm receiving 502 bad gateway errors when calling the function with no apparent reason.
After investigating i found out that the function is constantly restarting. by clicking the new support request in the portal blade for the function the automated checks are saying that the error is this one:

```
Inner Exception Type: System.TimeoutException
Total Occurrences: 3
Latest Exception Message: Initializing worker process failed
The operation has timed out.

Full Exception :
 System.TimeoutException : The operation has timed out.
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Grpc.GrpcWorkerChannel.PendingItem.OnTimeout() at /_/src/WebJobs.Script.Grpc/Channel/GrpcWorkerChannel.cs : 1455
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to depend on my code so i really don't know where to start.
I tried restarting and redeploying the function as the automated suggestions told me to do but to no avail. i've tried downgrading the `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker` package to a version i'm using in other functions that are working correctly but nothing changed. I haven't found anything useful by googling and i don't have a paid support plan.
Does anyone ever faced something like this?
I'm also wondering why there's a grpc worken when i'm not using grpc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had this problem when we updated one of our .Net 7 functions and it turned out to be an issue with the Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker package 1.13.0. Updating to 1.14.0 fixed the issue.

See https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/1459 for more information

Comment: I actually opened a ticket with Microsoft and they also acknowledged it was their problem, but they had me pin the runtime versione to 3.14 to mitigate the problem.
didn't really satisfy me but after a couple of days of testing seemes to be working.
But after your reply i might try to upgrade the worker package in a sandbox environment just to see if it also resolves the problem for me.
Many thanks!